# How to get PCB Layer Count, Size and No of pad from the Gerber?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building PCB Assembly website https://pcbmagic.com/pcb-quote.php. where I have to retrieve data from **Gerber file** and use them so is there any API or any other way to get their data.

there are so many websites that are using these features but I am not able to find the solution to how they are doing it.

https://www.nextpcb.com/quote-gerber

https://jlcpcb.com/

Comment: You can find the standard here; https://www.ucamco.com/en/guest/downloads/gerber-format 

For the layer count each layer is typically a separate file and to my knowledge the naming is not universal across packages. 

The size of the pcb/board outline will be another challenge for you as it can be defined on any layer or its own, eg some pcb designers will place is on the silk screen others will place it on its own mechanical layer.

Pad count also wont be simple as some cad packages use different features eg eagle uses strokes for pads.

Comment: @Chris hey I am not able to find any web API that can give data in reverse they have only an option in their own website to view. but I want to extract data from the Gerber and use them in my website. so is there any way to do so.

Comment: Gerber's are essentially just text files, the issue is that different CAD packages use different features of the standard. You might be best starting with something like this project https://github.com/tracespace/tracespace but i don't think by standard it will give you  all the information you require.